# Sanitize for all fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking for a proper way to sanitize all fields before saving results to database. There should be a way to do this, because user can add some html to any field in all user forms...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by 'sanitize' you mean 'avoid SQL-injection attacks', ActiveRecord should be magically handling it for you. However, it sounds like you're talking about preventing users from being able to enter html in a form and have that html processed when the form's content is displayed.

Rails templates automatically escape html in templates. Thus, if `foo = "<b>bar</b>"`, putting `<%= foo %>` in a Rails template will display the tags, not evaluate them. In order to force unescaped html, you would have to use the `raw` helper (`<%= raw(foo) %>` will not escape the tags).